# How to specify coordinate framework using plt.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal

I am trying to show a map in the matplotlib.pyplot window. As the figure indicates, the extent is [112.5,114.0,36.0,37.6]. However, I would like the extend to be [112.4,114.3,35.8,37.7], what measures should I take?
Look forward to your instructions.

Cheers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLYKp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this without the code you're using to generate your plot, but it is probably something like

```
plt.xlim(112.4, 114.3)
plt.ylim(35.8, 37.7)
```

If you're using the `ax` interface, instead it would be

```
ax.set_xlim(112.4, 114.3)
ax.set_ylim(35.8, 37.7)
```

Comment: from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

gdal.UseExceptions()
ds=gdal.Open('D:\PyGDAL_Case\DEM_ZH\Dem_Zh.tif')
band=ds.GetRasterBand(1)
elev1=band.ReadAsArray()
nrows,ncols=elev1.shape

yy=np.where(elev1>=0)[0]
xx=np.where(elev1>=0)[1]
zz=elev1[np.where(elev1>=0)]
elev_map=np.nan*np.empty((nrows,ncols))
elev_map[yy,xx]=zz

x0,dx,dxdy,y0,dydx,dy=ds.GetGeoTransform()
x1=x0+dx*ncols
y1=y0+dy*nrows

plt.imshow(elev_map,cmap='gist_earth_r',extent=[x0,x1,y1,y0])
plt.show()

Comment: Above is the code (I donot know how to edit an approriate style). Thanks Jeremy for kind instruction. I will try it.